# Scala SBT Version Dependency Binary Compatibility Error scala-xml

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project that I host on GitHub and I use scala-steward to keep my plugins and dependencies up to date. This worked for a while and now it is turning out to be a nightmare to use such auto updates. Here is the thing. In my plugins.sbt, I have a dependency to scoverage which was updated by scala-steward to version 2.0.6. But the pull request failed to pass through the compile stage and I see the following error:

```
[error] (update) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error] 
[error]     * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.1.0 (early-semver) is selected over {1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.1, 1.0.6}
[error]         +- org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-reporter_2.12:2.0.7 (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]         +- org.scalariform:scalariform_2.12:0.2.0             (depends on 1.0.6)
[error]         +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.16              (depends on 1.0.6)
[error]         +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.5.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 1.1.1)
[error]         +- com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.12:1.5.1             (depends on 1.2.0)
[error]         +- com.github.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.9.9 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12) (depends on 1.3.0)
[error]
```

First of all, it is good that such incompatibilities are reported during compile time to avoid any runtime surprises. But, I'm not sure how to get this fixed. Feels like I have hit a roadblock.

EDIT: Here is my actual project: https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator

Comment: scala-xml is bringing trouble at everyone :/ You migt try to force a specific version 2.x or look for updating all other plugins as well (assuming they have a version which is compatible with scala-xml 2.x).

Comment: That is going to be painful as I have a dozen plugins that I have to try out with different versions. Is there a way I could just kick out scala.xml from those plugins that are problematic?

Comment: Fixed it temporarily by using scoverage version to 1.9.3 but this is not what I actually want!

Comment: Can you provide a build.sbt and plugins.sbt? I mean, a minimal (problem) reproducible code of this files

Comment: probably you need to down your scalac-scoverage's version to 2.0.0  due to it's use scala-xml 2.1.0, while all others use 1.x.y version. Commonly when major version changed there are some problems while migrating to the new library version.
See pom.xml [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scoverage/scalac-scoverage-reporter_2.12/2.0.0)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin I have added the link to my project here for reference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had to do the following in my `project/plugins.sbt` file to get this error fixed:

```
ThisBuild / libraryDependencySchemes += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % VersionScheme.Always
```

I also added the following to my build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / evictionErrorLevel := Level.Info
```

But I guess I do not need that in my build.sbt. Hope this helps someone! The Scala community at discord helped me to get this fixed. Thanks to them!

Comment: Would be good to know the reasoning behind the change.

Comment: The binary incompatibility between scala-xml 1.x and 2.x is highly unlikely to cause trouble in practice, as the removed APIs are quite obscure. And anyway, this is the build-time classpath we're talking about, so any "runtime" problem would occur at build time, rather than in production. So it's almost certainly safe to just go ahead and use 2.x build-wide, even for plugins that were expecting 1.x, and that's what `VersionScheme.Always` does.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I "fixed" it by lowering akka-http version from 10.5.0 to 10.4.0, with akka 2.7.0. I also use `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.16")`. You also need to check some other libs if they depends on akka http. You may use `sbt dependencyTree` for that.

It was relativly unclear, but we can see `com.typesafe.play:twirl-api` in the error stack, and also we can see `scala-xml:2.1.0` as a child dependency of `akka-http-xml:10.5.0`

See also https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6997 -- you may find solution for this problem here